# How to create (x,y) coordinate in R

Tags: r

So I have 2 random variables X and Y

`x <- runif(1000,min=0,max=10)
lambda=2*x+0.2*x*sin(x)
y <- rpois(1000,lambda)`

And I want to create a vector J=(xi,yi) for i=1,...,1000

I'm not sure how to do this in the most efficient way.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have x and y already,
then you put them into a data frame, and using library sf (simple features) you may turn it into an spatial object, here it will come out with no projection, since it's an arbitrary set of data and not something geographical, otherwise you should ad st_set_crs() to the code below:

```
library(sf)
x <- runif(1000,min=0,max=10)
lambda=2*x+0.2*x*sin(x)
y <- rpois(1000,lam

bda)
    df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=runif(1000)) %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("x", "y"))

> df
Simple feature collection with 1000 features and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0.005045172 ymin: 0 xmax: 9.994533 ymax: 30
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 10 features:
               geometry
1   POINT (8.375505 20)
2  POINT (0.08116931 0)
3    POINT (3.786693 5)
4    POINT (7.68517 17)
5   POINT (9.363003 25)
6    POINT (5.114014 9)
7    POINT (5.70659 12)
8   POINT (9.936392 22)
9   POINT (9.164108 15)
10  POINT (7.524004 19)

plot(df)
```

Comment: Why are bringing sf into this? Seems unnecessary